# Netty - fire ReadTimeoutHandler if multiple reads in channel

Tags: java, netty

My I/O flow is following:

1. client sends data#1 to channel
2. server(handler) receives data from database according the client data and sends it to the client
3. client sends data#2 to channel
4. server(handler) receives data again from database according the client data and sends it back to the client and closes channel

If first read in channel takes too long, ReadTimeoutHandler fires exception as expected. But if first read is ok (= fast enough) and second read in channels takes too long, no TimeoutException is thrown and handler waits 5 minutes until it closes channel. It seems that ReadTimeoutHandler only works for the first read in channel. Is it even possible to get ReadTimeoutHandler work with multiple reads in the channel?

Used Netty version: 4.0.12

public class MyServer {

```
private static final class MyInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

...

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel channel) throws Exception {
        channel.pipeline().addLast(
                new ReadTimeoutHandler(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                new MyHandler(server, serverConnection));
    }

...

}
```

}

public class MyHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler {

```
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyHandler.class);

@Override
public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    super.channelActive(ctx);
}

@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String msg) throws Exception {
    Message message = database.getMessage(msg);
    ChannelFuture operation = ctx.writeAndFlush(message) 

if (message.isEnd()) operation.addListener(new CloseConverstationListener(ctx));
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    if (cause instanceof ReadTimeoutException) {
        LOG.error("ReadTimeoutException");
    } 
}

@Override
public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
    super.channelInactive(ctx);
}

private class CloseConverstationListener implements GenericFutureListener<ChannelFuture> {
    private final ChannelHandlerContext ctx;

    private CloseConverstationListener(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {
        future.channel().close().sync();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure you posted your full pipeline? There is no conversation from bytes to strings done.

Answer (score 0):

The ReadTimeoutHandler behavior is - If no read happens in a channel for the specified duration it will fire exception and close the channel. It is not for the delay in responding or processing a read.
At the beginning of channel read read flag is set to true and that is set to false when when read is complete. A scheduler runs which checks if the channel is open and has not read for the specified duration then it fires the exception and closes the connection.

> If first read in channel takes too long, ReadTimeoutHandler fires exception as expected.

The above does not sound correct to me.
If you want to timeout based on delay in writing a response, the you might consider WriteTimeoutHandler.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Still I think ReadTimeoutHandler doesn't work correctly in my case or I don't understand how it should work. It works for the first read in the channel in case it times out, but when the second (or third etc.) read comes, ReadTimeoutHandler doesn't raise exception e.g. when the client disconnects and there is no more read coming. ReadTimeoutHandler channelRead-method is called (again) but it will never raise an exception, because ReadTimeoutHandler state is after first read 1 (or 2?), and I understood correctly, it value should be 0 that scheduler task is fired again.

Comment: If client disconnects there are no active channels. When there is an active channel and there is no read that happened on the channel for the specified duration then this handler will throw Exception and close the channel. This is to prevent unwanted channel growth. HTH